# AngularJS, how do I select the correct default option element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem:
Given an array of Person objects, and a separate array of possible names (a super-set containing all the names found within our Person array),  how do I set the default option within the generated angular markup (see below).
I'm at a loss as to how to set the item in the names dropdown so that it represents the value of the name in the person object when the UI first loads.

[image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/hvIimscowGvO6Hje35RB?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
<button ng-click="loadData()">Load Data</button>

<ul ng-repeat="person in model.persons" >
  <li>name: {{person.name}}
    <select ng-select
            ng-options="item.name for item in data"
            ng-change="updateName(selectedName)"
            ng-model="selectedName">
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>age : {{person.age}}</li>
  <li>sex : {{person.sex}}</li>
</ul>

<script>

  var app=angular.module("app",[]);

  app.controller("test",function($scope){
    $scope.model={};
    $scope.model.persons=[];
    $scope.updateName=function(item){
      this.person.name = item.name;
    }
    $scope.data=[{name:'bob'},{name:'Sal'},{name:'Lee'},{name:"Fred"}];

    $scope.loadData=function(){

      $scope.model.persons=[{name:'bob',age:24,sex:'Yes Please'},
                      {name:'Sal',age:29,sex:'Not Today'},
                      {name:'Lee',age:34,sex:'If I must'}];

    }

  });

  angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple changes:

```
<ul ng-repeat="person in model.persons" ng-init="selectedName = person.name">

ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in data"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/hXGfRZQRz7owxpFZyudB?p=preview

Comment: Excellent! So simple.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should consider a sligthly different approach by using ng-repeat on options and [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) to denote a selected option:

```
<select ng-model="person.name">
    <option
            ng-repeat="item in data"
            ng-selected="item.name == person.name"
            ng-model="person.name">
        {{item.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

See it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gOO3iTXFFNWzFVMZv9GJ?p=preview

Comment: Appreciate the option. I up-voted you but went with Andy's answer as I did not want to use the ng-selected option if I could stay away from it. Just a stylistic consideration I suppose. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing, whatever works for you. Sometimes things just get too complex and we have to chop it up to smaller bits. You're welcome!