# ng-option with static link option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to add static option that represents a link to other page using ng-options.

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="person"
        ng-options="person.name for person in persons">
</select>
```

I am using select element with ng-options with predefined list of persons, where person is an object. I tried to use ng-repeat instead but this approach does not work:

```
<select ng-model="person" onChange = "window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="#/home">Anywhere</option>
    <option value="#/current" ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Varibale $scope.person gets the value "#/current". In this case linking works, but ng-model fails. Variable $scope.person should represent the selected person.

What I am expecting is that $scope.person has selected value, unless user choose "Anywhere", in which case he should be redirected to another page.

"#/home" and "#/current" represent the url location. "#/home"is a home page and "#/current" is a current page. onChange event redirects user to home page or reloads current page.

So when user select "Anywhere" he should be redirected to home page. For any other option user´s page won´t be changed.

Comment: You talk about ng-option but i can't see it. Try to re-explain the problem.

Comment: is `current` a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not mix native js and angularjs unless you know what exactly going on.

Use ng-change instead of onchange and check the value if it is value of 'Anywhere'. If it is then route, otherwise do nothing. In your approach you're redirecting in both cases.

```
<select ng-model="person" ng-change="selectHandler()">
    <option value="">Anywhere</option>
    <option value="{{prsn}}" ng-repeat="prsn in persons">
        {{prsn.name}}
    </option>
</select>

$scope.selectHandler = function(){
    if($scope.person == ''){
        console.log("route to /home");
        //ROUTE WITH $location.path
    }
}
```

Here is a working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/jsnpc6y5/2/)** for demo.

Answer (score 0):

in your ng-repeat try, you wrote:

```
ng-model="person"
```

which doesn't exist (because you do ng-repeat="person in persons")

try

```
ng-model="persons"
```

Comment: Yes, but I am using $scope.person variable in my controller. I don´t want to bind select element with an array of persons. I need selected person

Comment: why would you need the selected person and then have the list of all the persons ? if you want your select to automatically select the right element here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972601/angularjs-how-do-i-select-the-correct-default-option-element?rq=1here